# ZigFu Image Viewer in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I am working on a student project with the Kinect. Everything is working fine so far with the ZDK. Now we want to get the RGB Image from the Kinect camera.
There is a Script called ZigImageViewer, but it doesn't work for me. I also looked at the ZigDepthViewer which works for me. I set the "UpdateImage" setting in the Zig script to true. Is there any other setting I have to change?

I am using the Kinect for XBox, not the Kinect for Windows. My OS is Mac OSX 10.8. "Near Mode" is disabled before started and while running…

I got two exceptions:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "ZigFu" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

You probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "ZigFu". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

ZigImageViewer.Start () (at Assets/ZigFu/Scripts/Viewers/ZigImageViewer.cs:20)
```

and

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

ZigImageViewer.UpdateTexture (.ZigImage image) (at Assets/ZigFu/Scripts/Viewers/ZigImageViewer.cs:35)

ZigImageViewer.Zig_Update (.ZigInput input) (at Assets/ZigFu/Scripts/Viewers/ZigImageViewer.cs:44)

UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)

ZigInput:notifyListeners(String, Object)

ZigInput:HandleReaderNewUsersFrame(Object, NewUsersFrameEventArgs)

ZigInputOpenNI:OnNewUsersFrame(List`1)

ZigInputOpenNI:ProcessNewDepthFrame()

ZigInputOpenNI:Update()

ZigInput:Update()
```

I think the second exception is resulting out of the first exception. Here it says that there is no renderer, but the DepthViewer has no renderer attached, too.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Open scene "SimpleViewer" from Assets/ZigFu/SampleScenes directry.
There is Gameobject with name "Image". Use it as sample.